# How to select attribute with the same first word and optional for the last word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

i have this kind of element

```
<div class="clas"></div>
<div class="clas_temp"></div>
<div class="clastemp"></div>
<div class="clas_test"></div>
<div class="clas_tmp"></div>
<div class="clas_t"></div>
```

I need to select if the attribute `id` have the first word `clas` with the optional next value `_test`, `_t`, or `temp`.

i only know with selecting the first words using below syntax.

```
$( "div[class^='clas']" ).html( "insert!" );
```

Above snippet will select all class starting with `clas` but i need more specific with the second optional next value `_test`, `_t`, or`temp`. How could i do that ? The possible way was using Regex like `(_test|_t|temp)` but is there a regex grouping in jQuery ?

what i expect was the result will be like this.

```
<div class="clas"></div>
<div class="clas_temp">insert!</div>
<div class="clastemp"></div>
<div class="clas_test">insert!</div>
<div class="clas_tmp"></div>
<div class="clas_t">insert!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.filter( function )](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) in order to filter selected elements with a regex expr:

```
$("div[class^='clas']").filter((idx, ele) => ele.classList.value.match(/(_test|_t|temp)$/) != undefined)
```

or you can create your own selector:

```js
// add the new selector
;(function($){
    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
        classByRegex: function(a, b, c) {
            var cv = a.classList.value;  // get current class list
            var sel = c.pop();  // get the regex
            return cv.match(new RegExp(sel)) != undefined;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);


//use it

$( "div:classByRegex('^clas.*(_test|_t|temp)$')").text((idx, str) => str + ' insert!');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="clas">clas</div>
<div class="clas_temp">clas_temp</div>
<div class="clastemp">clastemp</div>
<div class="clas_test">clas_test</div>
<div class="clas_tmp">clas_tmp</div>
<div class="clas_t">clas_t</div>
```

Comment: WOAHHH! impresive! You made a custom selector..., that means there is no jquery built in for selecting id using regex ?

Comment: @Gagantous Yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

To match all three of those the selector will be pretty long :  `div[class^='clas'][class$='_temp'], div[class^='clas'][class$='_test'], div[class^='clas'][class$='_t']`

see the [`[attribute$=value]`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp) selector.

```js
var selector = "div[class^='clas'][class$='_temp'], div[class^='clas'][class$='_test'], div[class^='clas'][class$='_t']";

var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

console.log(els);
```

```html
<div class="clas"></div>
<div class="clas_temp"></div>
<div class="clastemp"></div>
<div class="clas_test"></div>
<div class="clas_tmp"></div>
<div class="clas_t"></div>
```

alternatively, you can do it in two steps..

```js
var selector = ", div[class^='clas'], div[class^='clas']";

var $els = $("div[class^='clas']").filter("[class$='_temp'], [class$='_test'], [class$='_t']");

$els.each(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clas"></div>
<div class="clas_temp"></div>
<div class="clastemp"></div>
<div class="clas_test"></div>
<div class="clas_tmp"></div>
<div class="clas_t"></div>
```

Comment: so i need to select all the three possible elements ?

Comment: @Gagantous - yes, i added another jquery specific alternative. however it might just be easier to use the classnames themselves.